# shorted Jquery by using each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i shorted this jquery by using each() function? or have another method to shorted this jquery?

```js
            $("div.body-t-option-1").hover(function() {
                $(".body-t-img-2,.body-t-img-3,.body-t-img-4").hide();
                $(".body-t-img-1").show();
                $(".body-t-img-1").addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
            });

            $("div.body-t-option-2").hover(function() {
                $(".body-t-img-1,.body-t-img-3,.body-t-img-4").hide();
                $(".body-t-img-2").show();
                $(".body-t-img-2").addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
            });

            $(".body-t-option-3").hover(function() {
                $(".body-t-img-1,.body-t-img-2,.body-t-img-4").hide();
                $(".body-t-img-3").show();
                $(".body-t-img-3").addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
            });

            $(".body-t-option-4").hover(function() {
                $(".body-t-img-1,.body-t-img-2,.body-t-img-3").hide();
                $(".body-t-img-4").show();
                $(".body-t-img-4").addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
            });
```

Comment: Please provide the full code to know which tag to traverse in a loop

Answer (score 0):

how are u?
suggestion, currently it is recommended to use the events as follows

```
$(document).on('hover', 'div.body-t-option-1', () => {
    //code...
});

$(document).on('click', '#something', () => {
    //code...
});
```

now, regarding the question, let me suggest that you reformulate it by adding more information for example with an html template in order to understand your desired output